# Improve 3D plot as area with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some run-time data from my program with different configurations and want to plot which configuration takes how much time. I was told to do this with gnuplot but I never used this before.

My input file is in this format: the x-axis has the range [2;24], y-range is [0:50] (these are the seconds) and z-range goes from 1000000 to 8000000.

```
#X Z Y
2;1000000;2.868927
2;2000000;3.424788
2;3000000;4.678282
2;4000000;4.668475
2;5000000;5.202231
2;6000000;6.911772
2;7000000;6.984136
2;8000000;7.976616
4;1000000;1.918312
4;2000000;2.530352
4;3000000;3.704574
4;4000000;3.744970
4;5000000;4.622870
4;6000000;5.390530
4;7000000;6.733730
4;8000000;7.556841  
...
```

UPDATE: I have changed the input file for pm3d, so the new input file is like:

```
#X Y Z

2 1000000 2.868927
2 2000000 3.424788
2 3000000 4.678282
2 4000000 4.668475
2 5000000 5.202231
2 6000000 6.911772
2 7000000 6.984136
2 8000000 7.976616

4 1000000 1.918312
4 2000000 2.530352
4 3000000 3.704574
4 4000000 3.744970
4 5000000 4.622870
4 6000000 5.390530
4 7000000 6.733730
4 8000000 7.556841
...
```

I tried a little bit and read from some pages how to getting started with gnuplot but I still don't know what would be the best visualization for this input. My (updated) gnuplot file is:

```
set pm3d
set ticslevel 0
set isosample 40,40
set hidden3d
set xrange[2:24]
set zrange[0:50]
set yrange[1000000:8000000]
set xtics 2
set ztics 5
set ytics 1000000
show label
set view 45,20,1.0,1.5
splot "~/Schreibtisch/number1_input_fixed.dat" using 1:2:3 with lines
```

My idea was to have a 3 dimensional plot, where the y-axis specifies the runtime. By this plot one can see the good and bad configurations by looking for high/low spots on the surface. Here is an image of the current plot

[image]

Is this kind of visualization a good choice? What can I improve to get a better visualization of the data? I almost never did a 3D plot so I have no clue what can be improved here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `set pm3d map`, so you'd have a 2D plot with the third dimension being the color scale. In your current plot, both the z-axis and color scale relate to the same quantity. By using a map it should be easier to see what you want. Instead of looking at "high/low spots on the surface, you can look at different colors to judge what is good/bad in your case.

Have a look at the color palettes you can use:

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html

Even though I also like the 3D plots, 2D plots with a color scale, or points with variable sizes, is usually better (IMHO).

Comment: If I change to `set pm3d map` the colors complete disappear and I only have the grid. Do I have more to change? I also tried to change to "plot" instead of "splot".

Comment: Sorry, you need to do `splot "~/Schreibtisch/number1_input_fixed.dat" using 1:2:3 with points pt 7 ps 1 palette`. That will use the default color scheme.

Comment: If you meant that it should be a 2D plot I had to change from `splot` to `plot`. Now I have a 2D plot where the colors identify the z-axis values, thanks. But in my opinion, it is harder to recognize the difference between the measure points on the plot. One has to look at the points and check for the color instead for looking of the lowest/highest spot on the area.